# python - for loop running for len(A)-1 times omitting 0

Tags: python, loops

I am running the below code.

**Can anybody explain to me why the for loop in my code is not running for p=7?** I meant to run the loop len(A)-1 times (omitting 0). I used

```
for p in xrange(1,n-1)
```

There is the whole routine

```
 A=[-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1]
 P=[-1, 2, -2, 3, 4, -2, 0, 1]

def solution(A):
    results=[]
    n=len(A)

    for p in xrange(1,n-1):

            if P[p-1]==P[n-1]-P[p-1]-A[p]:
                results.append(p)

    return results
```

Comment: Could you cut this down to a [mcve]? I'm guessing the answer is because `range` is half open, i.e. `range(1, 7)` excludes `7`, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: Edited. I was focusing on the beginning of the loop, I thought I was doing something wrong there. Still many things to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(a, b)` (or `xrange`) iterates from `a` to `b-1` included. So the loop with `xrange(1,n-1)` will run `n-2` times.

Look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)!